# How to assign sql output to a variable in Linux?

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

I have a shell script like this:

**a.sh**

```
   GetVersion()
    {
     sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" <<EOF
        SET HEADING OFF
        SET FEEDBACK OFF
        SET LINESIZE 3800
        SET TRIMSPOOL ON
        SET TERMOUT OFF
        SET SPACE 0
        SET PAGESIZE 0
    SELECT version from v$instance
    EOF
    }
GetVersion
```

What i need is to get the output of this function to a variable. Because i'm going to write some if-else statements depending on variable.

So the question is, how can i get the output of the `GetVersion()` function and assign it to a variable?

Comment: i fixed my comment. it works well thanks. just put this as solution and i will mark.

Comment: The $instance is a variable inside the shell above? If yes and its working then this helps me also alot

Comment: @GeorgeGeorgiou it's an sql command that gets data from v$instance view.